# Registering a custom Spree Calculator not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

Following the docs on this page...
http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/calculators.html

I've created a class in models/spree/calculators/

```
module Spree 
class Calculator::ZipTax <  Calculator
  def self.description
  "Calculates Tax Rates From Zipcode in TaxRates Table"
   end
    def compute(computable)
  case computable
    when Spree::Order
      compute_order(computable)
    when Spree::LineItem
      compute_line_item(computable)
  end
end
    def compute_order(order)
    zipcode = order.bill_address.zipcode[0,5]
    zip = TaxTable.where(:zipcode => zipcode).first
    if(zip.present?)
      rate = zip.combined_rate
        order.line_items.sum(&:total) * rate
    else 
      0
    end

end
  end
end
```

And in initializers/spree.rb I've added:

```
config = Rails.application.config
config.spree.calculators.tax_rates << Spree::Calculator::ZipTax
```

But I can not get Rails to start. I get undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) on the initializer/spree.rb file.

How do I register a custom Calculator? Using Spree 1.3.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to wrap your configuration in an after_initialize:

in config/application.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
  config.spree.calculators.tax_rates << Spree::Calculator::ZipTax
end
```

You're encountering an error because the spree calculators haven't been initialized at that point in your application boot process, so you're trying to append the calculator to something that's nil.

Another method, commonly used in Spree extensions is to do the following:

```
initializer 'spree.register.calculators' do |app|
  app.config.spree.calculators.shipping_methods << Spree::Calculator::ZipTax
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Next time I'll know better than to follow Spree's docs that closely ;)

Comment: On a side note for shipping calculators make sure that the class name is `Spree::Shipping::<YourCalculatorName>` for your calculator to show up in the admin panel https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2a3f91229f65e1c0c7e16eb47da455d3488195bc/core/app/models/spree/shipping_method.rb#L50. Soon to release versions of spree just require that shipping calculators inherit from `Spree::ShippingCalculator` https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/82fd0e0f762f17493c1609a998192272dab83e07/core/app/models/spree/shipping_method.rb#L50

Comment: I think this should actually be a class name of Spree::Calculator::Shipping::<YourCalculatorName> to get it to show up in the Admin Panel.

Comment: They really need to add this to the documentation.